# Python Newbie - Errors all of a sudden appearing when starting Python

Tags: python

As the title suggests I'm new with Python.  Been enjoying learning something new.  All of a sudden though, when I start up Python, I'm seeing the following errors.  What broke and how do I fix it, please?

```
(base) C:\Users\cdehaven\python>python
Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 15:18:16) [MSC v.1916 64 b
it (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\DeepLearning\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 410, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "F:\DeepLearning\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 1
65, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "F:\DeepLearning\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history
.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "F:\DeepLearning\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2477: cha
racter maps to <undefined>
>>>
```

Comment: There may be a problem with readline or in config files(?) Have you tried "conda update --all"? this is one of the first steps when I start up Anaconda. Use the command "import readline;print(readline.__file__)" to see what file has the problem.

Comment: You are using Windows and edited a Python file that was not using encoding='utf-8'.

Comment: Thanks for the help, oax....   Turned out to be a python history file.  I just deleted it.